# Paint in a part of JPanel without repaint the rest

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, repaint

I'm trying to make a Mastermind in Java. The code isn't really difficult, but I want to have a very good interface. I have a JPanel which take all my JFrame, and I paint this JPanel with surchargind `repaint()` method:

```
//method to draw elements on the map
public void paint(Graphics g) {
   super.paintComponents(g);
   Graphics gr;
   gr = MasterMindPane.getGraphics();

   img = MasterMindPane.getToolkit().getImage("images/plateau4-8.jpg");
   gr.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 600, 720, this);

   gr = bouleRougePane.getGraphics();
   img = bouleRougePane.getToolkit().getImage("images/bouleRouge.png");
   //gr.drawImage(img, 535, 303, 45, 45, this);
   gr.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 45, 45, this);
   gr = bouleOrangePane.getGraphics();
   img = bouleOrangePane.getToolkit().getImage("images/bouleOrange.png");
   //gr.drawImage(img, 535, 303, 45, 45, this);
   gr.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 45, 45, this);
}
```

When I click on one image, which have a Panel, I draw a yellow circle like that :

```
private void bouleRougePaneMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                            
   Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) MasterMindPane.getGraphics();

   for(int i = 0; i<4; i++)
   {
      g2d.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
      g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(3));
      g2d.drawOval(78+i*70, 106+etape*50, 35, 35);
   }
}
```

And when I select a hole, I want to delete the circle, which only indicates where the gamer can play.

But I don't know how to delete the circle or repaint just a part of my Image because it costs a lot to repaint all.

Comment: Have you tried invoking the `repaint(Rectangle r)` method?

Comment: Yes I tried but repaint(Rectangle r) erase all my picture, and repaint only the part specified in the Rectangle

Comment: What do you mean it erases all your picture? The purpose of using repaint(Rectangle r) is to have only that part repaint and that's what you are asking in your question; I must be misunderstanding something here. Other question, what is `MasterMindPane.getGraphics()`? Why don't you use the provided `Graphics g`?

Comment: When i try this code :private void panelDynamicMouseClick(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt, JPanel jp) {
    System.out.println(jp.getName());
    Rectangle rec = new Rectangle(100,100,200,300);
    repaint(rec);
} The line repaint(rec) is underlined in red in netbeans. It seems to be forbidden

Comment: And this is good : System.out.println(jp.getName());
    Rectangle rec = new Rectangle(100,100,200,300);
    repaint(10,10,20,30); But it repaint all, and not selected coords

Comment: you're approaching that the wrong way: a) never-ever use getGraphics b) never-ever do any potentially costly tasks (like f.i. loading an image from the file system)

Comment: Ok, but do you have any example about what I should do ? I really don't understand, and i follow some tutorials to do what I did..

Comment: do you meaning these types of [Mastermind](http://www.google.com/search?q=Mastermind&hl=cs&client=firefox-a&hs=jd9&rls=org.mozilla:cs:official&prmd=imvnsa&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=SipeT4awKML_4QTFptjfDw&ved=0CHsQsAQ&biw=1590&bih=939)

Comment: I am having this very question......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very simple way is to use `paintImmediately(x,y,w,h);`

This repaints only the specified area that starts at pixel (x,y) with width w and height h.

Answer (score 0):

You can set clip Shape to the thick oval and fill it.

Create the big oval Shape via BasicStroke with thick line.