# JPanel repaint does not work

Tags: java, graphics, jpanel, paintcomponent, repaint

I am developing a graphic project in java using swing and awt libraries. I am looking for a method that allow me to draw very fast on my JPanel. I tried various methods: overriding paintComponent, calling repaint(x, y, width, heigth).. But in  all cases i have to repaint ALL the screen! I have a background and a small image in front of it that changes every few time. i am looking for a method that allow me to paint on the screen only the small image, i don't need to repaint the background too, because it is always the same, and the small image is always at the same coords. for example in C++ i painted the background and then i only painted the small images in front of it using putimage (graphics.h), so that it was very very fast. Do someone have some tips?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Paint in a part of JPanel without repaint the rest](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9668564/paint-in-a-part-of-jpanel-without-repaint-the-rest)

Comment: `i don't need to repaint the background too, because it is always the same, and the small image is always at the same coords` - so why do you need to repaint anything if the backround image and the small image are the same? Why are you trying to do custom painting. Just use a JLabel for the background image. Then you can also add a second smaller label to the background label.

Comment: yes, but the small image change, in my program i have 3 image that change every n milliseconds, and i want to repaint directly only the small part where the image is placed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had some experience with game programming and usually a JPanel is used as canvas. Now to paint on it you would write a simple loop which continuously buffers an image and later paints it to the screen. So on initialisation you create a Graphics or Graphics2D object which is passed to a buffer() method. After painting a BufferedImage with the Instance of Graphics, some paint() method paints the BufferedImage to the screen.

When only painting the background once, previously drawn images will still be visible. If all your images are the same size, you don't have to bother but I still recommend repainting your background as well.

Have a look at the book **Killer Game Programming In Java** for further information, it's a great reference.

Comment: ok but i still have a doubt.. this is my code
    
    class ImagePanel extends JPanel
    {
        ImagePanel() {/* init */}
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
        {
            // this method paint ALL the scene
        }
        void myRepaintMethod()
        {
            // what should i write here to repaint only 
            // that small area -> x1=12, y1=304, x2=710, y2=500
        }
    }
    
   what should i do here?

Comment: I'm note sure but what are you actually trying to achieve with only partially redrawing the image on the canvas?

Answer (score 0):

Tips:

- Paint static images to a BufferedImage and then draw that within the paintComponent using `Graphics#drawImage(...)`
- You do know that the `repaint(...)` method is overloaded and that one overload can accept a Rectangle parameter, limiting the area of repainting.